# Reading all data in list with duplicate data inside

Tags: c#, arrays, list, debugging, unity-game-engine

I am having a problem reading all the list using for loop with duplicate data inside the list.

This is my code:

```
List<string> MyList= new List<string>();         

void Start ()
{
    MyList.Add("SampTable");
    MyList.Add("Respawn");
    MyList.Add("SampTable");
}

public void ReadList()
{
    int TagNum =  MyList.Count;
    for(int i = 0; i < TagNum; i++)
    {
       Debug.Log(TagNum);
       Debug.Log(MyList[i]);
    }
}
```

However the output is always

3

SampTable

Respawn

I want the output like

3

SampTable

Respawn

SampTable

Comment: what is your question ? do you want to get non-duplicated items ?

Comment: I want the output like

3

SampTable

Respawn

SampTable

Comment: OP is saying they want to output every item but even dupes, but log is not printing the duplicates, is that correct @kerboy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct (Except when you log the list count. You should do that outside of the loop).

Check if you have enabled `Collapse` in Unity console window:

[image]

`Collapse` option collapses same logs together.
If you enable this option and have duplicate log entries, You will see a little number on the right side of each log that indicates how many times that log occurred.

Turn this option off to see your duplicate logs in separate entry.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
List<string> MyList = new List<string>();

void Start()
{
    MyList.Add("SampTable");
    MyList.Add("Respawn");
    MyList.Add("SampTable");
}

public void ReadList()
{
    int TagNum = MyList.Count;
    Debug.Log(TagNum);
    for (int i = 0; i < TagNum; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(MyList[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

> 3
>
> SampTable
>
> Respawn
>
> SampTable